# I'm not sure how to add spaces to the small triangles to make it into a larger triangle

Tags: java

So basically my program will print this type of triangle when user input a number that module 8 and equal to 0. So a larger triangle is made out of smaller triangle with a base of 4. This is how a triangle look like when i input number 16:

```
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * * *   * * *   * * *   * * *
      * *     * *     * *     * *
       *       *       *       *
        * * * * * * * * * * * *
         * * *   * * *   * * *
          * *     * *     * * 
           *       *       *
            * * * * * * * *
             * * *   * * *
              * *     * *
               *       *
                * * * *
                 * * *
                  * *
                   *
```

but mine turned out like this:

```
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * * *   * * *   * * *   * * *
      * *     * *     * *     * *
       *       *       *       *
    * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * * *   * * *   * * *
      * *     * *     * * 
       *       *       *  
    * * * * * * * * 
     * * *   * * *  
      * *     * *    
       *       *    
    * * * *
     * * * 
      * *   
       *
```

I'm not so sure how to add the spaces. Can someone help me out? Here is my code:

```
 ...
            System.out.println("Please enter the length:");
            int length = scan.nextInt();;

            //length must be longer than 2
            if (length <= 1){
                System.out.println("Sorry :(! Length must be 2 or higher");
            }

            //if user enter a number that can divide by 8 and has no remainder, then
            //loop to print out a beautiful triangle
            else if(length%8==0) {
                int numOfTriangle  = length/4;
                System.out.println("Here is your beautiful triangle :D \n");

                for (int rowOfTri = numOfTriangle; rowOfTri > 0; rowOfTri--){
                    for(int i = 0; i < rowOfTri; i++){
                        printBase();
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                    for(int i = 0; i < rowOfTri; i++){
                        printThree();
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                    for(int i = 0; i < rowOfTri; i++){
                        printTwo();
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                    for(int i = 0; i < rowOfTri; i++){
                        printOne();
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

            //any other number will print a normal triangle
            else{
                System.out.println("Here is your beautiful triangle :D \n");
                for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++){
                    for (int j = 1; j <= length; j++){
                        if (j < i){
                            System.out.print(" ");
                        } else {
                            System.out.print("*");
                            System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }

            }

            //asking users if they want to print again
            System.out.println("\nDo you want to print another triangle? Type Yes or No.");

            //scan for string answer
            String againChoice = scan.next();

            //if answer start with Y or y then answer is Yes.
            if(againChoice.startsWith("Y") || againChoice.startsWith("y")){
                printAgain = true;
            }

            //if answer start with N or n then answer is No.
            else if(againChoice.startsWith("N") || againChoice.startsWith("n")){
                printAgain = false;
                System.out.println("Bye!");
            }

            // set input to none again
        } while (printAgain == true);

    }
    //methods to print a triangle
    public static void printBase(){
        System.out.print("* * * * ");
    }
    public static void printThree(){
        System.out.print(" * * *  ");
    }
    public static void printTwo(){
        System.out.print("  * *   ");
    }
    public static void printOne(){
        System.out.print("   *    ");
    }
    public static void printSpace(){
        System.out.print("    ");
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe just some additional spaces/tabs to your '*" when you start to draw the triangle at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your printing code like this and it works properly:

```
else if (length % 8 == 0) {
            int layer = 0;
            int numOfTriangle = length / 4;
            System.out.println("Here is your beautiful triangle :D \n");

            for (int rowOfTri = numOfTriangle; rowOfTri > 0; rowOfTri--) {
                for (int i = 0; i < layer; i++) {
                    printSpace();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < rowOfTri; i++) {
                    printBase(layer);
                }
                System.out.println();
                for (int i = 0; i < layer; i++) {
                    printSpace();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < rowOfTri; i++) {
                    printThree(layer);
                }
                System.out.println();
                for (int i = 0; i < layer; i++) {
                    printSpace();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < rowOfTri; i++) {
                    printTwo(layer);
                }
                System.out.println();
                for (int i = 0; i < layer; i++) {
                    printSpace();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < rowOfTri; i++) {
                    printOne(layer);
                }
                System.out.println();
                layer++;
            }
            System.out.println();
```